# Angular universal - what are the universal-only providers?

Tags: angular, angular-universal

In the doc https://angular.io/guide/universal#app-server-module

I can read

```
providers: [
   // Add universal-only providers here
],
```

so what are universal-only providers ?

Can you give me an example, please?

Comment: it is server module specific services

Comment: Can you give me an example, please?

Answer (score 1):

Its Server module specific services like

```
providers: [
    {provide: 'WindowToken', useValue: null},
    ServerSessionCache,
    ServerSessionStorage
]
```

where WindowToken is used for window object, because i want to use `window` object on browser module, so in case of browser module

browser module

```
providers: [
   {provide: 'WindowToken', useValue: window}
    ....
]
```

but in server module i dont want to use `window object`

```
providers: [
   {provide: 'WindowToken', useValue: null}
   ....
]
```